# How to prevent arithmetic overflow error when using SUM on INT column?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, int, sum, overflow, arithmeticexception

I am using **SQL Server 2008 R2** and I have an `INT` column where the data inserted never surpasses the max `INT`, but I have a query which uses the `SUM` function which when executed surpasses the max `INT` limit and throws the error mentioned in the title.

I want to be able to execute this query without changing the column type from `INT` to `BIGINT`.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT    UserId,
          SUM( PokemonExp )     AS TotalExp,
          MAX( PokemonLevel )   AS MaxPokeLevel

FROM      mytable

GROUP BY  UserId
ORDER BY  TotalExp DESC
```

***Note:** The `PokemonExp` column is of type `INT`.*

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Type of expression in [`SUM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) determines return type.

Try the following:

```sql
SELECT    UserId,
          SUM( CAST( PokemonExp AS BIGINT ))  AS TotalExp,
          MAX( PokemonLevel )                 AS MaxPokeLevel

FROM      mytable

GROUP BY  UserId
ORDER BY  TotalExp DESC
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the same seems to happen with AVG, even if it's just the sum of your values that's overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change the column type to `BIGINT` to get a proper sum.

Just `CAST` or `CONVERT` `PokemonExp` to `BIGINT` *before* you perform the `SUM` like follows:

```sql
SUM( CAST( PokemonExp AS BIGINT ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted type of expression in `SUM` determines return type.

Try the following:

```
SELECT    UserId,
          SUM( CAST( PokemonExp AS BIGINT ))  AS TotalExp,
          MAX( PokemonLevel )                 AS MaxPokeLevel

FROM      mytable

GROUP BY  UserId
ORDER BY  TotalExp DESC
```

Comment: Does `CAST( PokemonExp AS BIGINT )` not explicitly cast the result to `BIGINT`, which was the opposite of what OP wanted?