# How to prevent arithmetic overflow error when using SUM on INT column while inserting?

Tags: sql-server

My question is similar to the one in 
[How to prevent arithmetic overflow error when using SUM on INT column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289310/how-to-prevent-arithmetic-overflow-error-when-using-sum-on-int-column) but limit the int value.

I want to insert the max limit of the int(2147483647) if the `sum(column_name)` exceeds the int limit, how to do it? Note: TotalExp datatype is INT

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE
SELECT    UserId,
          SUM( PokemonExp )     AS TotalExp,
          MAX( PokemonLevel )   AS MaxPokeLevel
FROM      mytable
GROUP BY  UserId
ORDER BY  TotalExp DESC
```

Comment: You will need to cast  your data type to bigint

Comment: Try replacing your current `SUM(PokemonExp) AS TotalExp` with `CASE WHEN SUM(PokemonExp) >= 2147483647 THEN 2147483647 ELSE SUM(PokemonExp) END AS TotalExp`. Note: Pseudo-code.

Comment: @SchmitzIT when you sum integer columns that would result in a value above 2147483647, you get an overflow error. Which means your suggestion doesn't work. You can try this example: `SELECT CASE WHEN sum(a)> 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM (values(1),(2147483647)) x(a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert PokemonExp to bigint

```
INSERT INTO NEWTABLE
SELECT
  UserId,
  CASE WHEN 
    SUM( CAST(PokemonExp as BIGINT)) > 2147483647
         THEN 2147483647 
         ELSE SUM( CAST(PokemonExp as BIGINT))
         END AS TotalExp,
  MAX( PokemonLevel ) AS MaxPokeLevel
FROM      mytable
GROUP BY  UserId
ORDER BY  TotalExp DESC
```